# Automatic Count Row and update results to another table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables
one is `tbl_candidates` and the other one is `tbl_votes`

`tbl_candidates` contains the information of candidates and their total votes.
`sid` is the `userid` of the candidate.

```
   id | partyid | positionid | sid | votecount
   -------------------------------------------
   1  |    1    |     1      | 444 |     0
   2  |    2    |     1      | 555 |     0
   3  |    1    |     2      | 666 |     0
   4  |    2    |     2      | 777 |     0
```

`tbl_votes` contains vote counts.

```
   id | partyid | positionid | sid | voterid
   -------------------------------------------
   1  |    1    |     1      | 444 |   1111
   2  |    1    |     2      | 666 |   1111
   3  |    1    |     1      | 444 |   2222
   4  |    1    |     2      | 666 |   2222
```

So would it possible to count the number of rows for each candidate(sid) in the `tbl_votes` and update the `votecount` on `tbl_candidates` ON PAGE LOAD?

The result would hopefully be like

```
   id | partyid | positionid | sid | votecount
   -------------------------------------------
   1  |    1    |     1      | 444 |     2
   2  |    2    |     1      | 555 |     0
   3  |    1    |     2      | 666 |     2
   4  |    2    |     2      | 777 |     0
```

I already tried many variations of queries but they were silly as I failed.

**IN ADDITION**

I tried to udpate the vote counts in tbl_votes upon registration of votes. Failed so im trying to udpate vote counts on page load. Here is my code.

```
        <div class="content">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT count(id) as id1 FROM tbl_positions";
$result = $DBcon->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $id1=$row["id1"];
    }

} else {

}

?>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT count(id) as id2 FROM tbl_votes where userid='$usersid'";
$result = $DBcon->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $id2=$row["id2"];
    }

} else {

}
?>

                <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" data-background-color="purple">
                        <h4 class="title">Ballot</h4>
                        <p class="category">Select one each position.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                <form method="post" action="vote.php"             enctype="multipart/form-data">



            <?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_positions";
$result = $DBcon->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $pospos=$row["position"];
 $posid=$row["id"];


  ?>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" data-background-color="    <?php 
 if ($posid % 3 == 0) {
echo "red";
} elseif ($posid % 2 == 0) {
echo "green";
}else{
 echo "orange";
}                               ?>">
                                <h4 class="title"><?php echo $pospos;?></h4>
                                <p class="category">New employees on 15th     September, 2016</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead class="text-warning">
                                      <th></th>
                                      <th></th>
                                      <th>Photo</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Partylist</th>

                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>


                                                    <?php 
$sql2 = "SELECT u.*,p.*,d.*,c.*
        FROM tbl_users u
        JOIN tbl_candidates c on c.sid = u.sid
        JOIN tbl_party p on c.partyid = p.id
        JOIN tbl_positions d on c.positionid = d.id
        WHERE c.status='1' AND d.id='$posid'
        ";
$result2 = $DBcon->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {

  while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
 $csid=$row2["sid"];
 $fn=$row2["firstname"];
 $ln=$row2["lastname"];
 $cpar=$row2["partyname"];
 $cimage=$row2["image"];
 $vc1=$row2["votecount"];
 $vc2=$vc1+1;

?>

<tr>
<td><input type="number" name="voted" value="<?php echo $vc2; ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $csid; ?>" name="<?php echo     $posid; ?>" required></td>
<td>
<ul class="enlarge"> 
<li>
<img style="width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:100%;"     src="candidateimages/<?php echo $cimage; ?>">
<span> <!--span contains the popup image-->
<img style="width:200px;height:200px;border-radius:100%;" src="candidateimages/<?php echo $cimage; ?>" /> <!--popup image-->

</span>
</li>
</ul>
</td><td><?php echo $fn; ?> <?php echo $ln; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $cpar; ?></td></tr>
    <?php }?>
    <?php
       if (isset($_POST['submitvote'])){
     $please=$_POST[$posid];
     $please2=$_POST["voted"];

     if ($id1>$id2){


         $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_votes (sid,posid,userid,date,time)
VALUES ('$please','$posid','$usersid','$date','$time')";

     if ($DBcon->query($sql) === TRUE) {

     $sql = "UPDATE tbl_candidates SET votecount='$please2' WHERE sid='$csid' AND     positionid='$posid'";
     if ($DBcon->query($sql) === TRUE) {

      $sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET votestatus='1' WHERE sid='$usersid'";
     if ($DBcon->query($sql) === TRUE) {    
      echo'<script>window.location="vote.php?success";</script>';
     } else {
     }
     } else {
     }





     } else {

     }

     }


  }
 ?>

   <?php

} else {
  echo "<td></td><td>No candidates</td>";
} 

  ?>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


 <?php
    }

} else {
  echo "No Positions";
} ?>



                <button type="submit" name="submitvote" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Submit</button>




                 </form>    
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

The problem with my code is the wrong values are being updated into the tbl_votes... Would it also be possible using this method?

Comment: Post the queries that you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this query,

```
UPDATE tbl_candidates 
   SET votecount = (
        SELECT COUNT(sid) 
        FROM tbl_votes 
        WHERE tbl_votes.sid = tbl_candidates.sid 
        GROUP BY sid
       );
```